# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module due to:

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, requirejs

First I've to say that I've looked every existing question relating to my problem, but I've found nothing dealing with my problem.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Arrows due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Arrows' is not available! You either misspelled the         
module     name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify ...    
<omitted>...2)
```

**my index.html:**

```
<html ng-app='Arrows'>
    <head>
        <title>Arrows</title>
        <script data-main="app" src="modules/require.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
        <script src="modules/angular-1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/angular-1.2.21/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='menuController'>       
        <div ng-view>
            {{ message }}
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**my app.js:**

```
define([
    './controller/menu',
    './controller/game'
], function( 
    menu,
    game
) {

    var Arrows = angular.module('Arrows', ['ngRoute']);

    Arrows.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/menu.html',
                controller  : 'menuController'
            })
            .when('/game', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/game.html',
                controller  : 'gameController'
            })
            .otherwise( {
                redirectTo: '/', 
                controller: 'menuController'
            }); 
    });

    Arrows.controller('gameController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'hello! Its working!';
    });

    Arrows.controller('menuController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'hello! Its working!';
    });
});
```

No clue what to do there. I mean, I loaded *angular-route.js*, what is the answer to most questions concerning this error. And I made sure to write *ng-app='Arrows'* inside the html-tag.

Comment: Guess it is your lazyloading that might be causing this issue... Instead of `ng-app="Arrows"` on the html, try using manual bootstrapping.. `angular.bootstrap(document, ['Arrows']);`

Comment: I already asked my 'mentor' about this. But he said i can load it in head and don't need to bootstrap angularjs.

Comment: I did so and this is the reaction:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'menuController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: "You should list angular as dependency as well right?" Sorry, but I dont know how to do...

Comment: I don't see the link to your own script in the HTML.

Comment: I use require.js. That's the link to my app.js:
 <script data-main="app" src="modules/require.js"></script>

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with angular and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: http://gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js/

Answer (score 1):

As you are using require.js you have to bootstrap your AngularJS application in a special way. Read this article - https://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/ - and try to incorporate what is described there for your specific case.

In the end you will use something like

```
define([
   'require',
   'angular'
], function (require, ng) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
       ng.bootstrap(document, ['Arrows']);
   });
});
```

Comment: In the tutorial you've shared, he uses bower to load the dependencies. That's acutally not the way I want to go...